# Find all integers such as $7 \mid(5^n +4^n+2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Find all integers n such as 7 devides
$5^n +4^n+2$

With frt we know that
$5^6=1[7]$
But I don't know how to continue from here!
I tried writing
$5(5^n-1) +4(4^n-1)+2$
But the main issue persists with the power of n and I cant reach a linear combination for the values of n
Plz help out !

Comment: Since $a^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$, just check $n = 0, 1, 2 ,\dots, 5$. If there are any solutions, add $6k, k\in\mathbb N$ to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$4^3\equiv 1\mod 7$$
$$5^3\equiv -1\mod 7$$

Answer (score 1):

$5^1\equiv \color{red}5\pmod 7$

$5^2\equiv 25 \equiv \color{blue}4 \pmod 7$

$5^3\equiv 5\cdot 4 \equiv 20 \equiv \color{green}6 \pmod 7$

$5^4\equiv 5\cdot 6 \equiv 30 \equiv \color{purple}2 \pmod 7$

$5^5 \equiv 5\cdot 2 \equiv \color{orange}3 \pmod 7$

$5^6\equiv 5\cdot 3 \equiv 15 \equiv \color{aqua}1 \pmod 7$

thus the powers of $5$ cycle $5^{6m}\equiv 1,5^{6m+1}\equiv 5, 5^{6m+2}\equiv 4, 5^{6m+3}\equiv 6, 5^{6m+4}\equiv 2, 5^{6m+5}\equiv 3$ for $m\in\mathbb{N}^*\cup\{0\}$ (I'm not sure whether you're definition of $\mathbb{N}$ contains $0$ or not).

$4^1\equiv \color{lime}4 \pmod 7$

$4^2\equiv 16\equiv \color{fuchsia}2 \pmod 7$

$4^3\equiv 4\cdot 2 \equiv 8 \equiv \color{teal}1 \pmod7$

thus similarly $4^{6m,6m+3}\equiv 1, 4^{6m+1,6m+4}\equiv 4, 4^{6m+2,6m+5}\equiv 2$ for $m\in \mathbb{N}^*\cup\{0\}$

need to check*:

$\color{red}{5}+\color{lime}{4}+2\equiv 11 \equiv 4 \not\equiv 0\pmod 7$

$\color{blue}{4}+\color{fuchsia}{2}+2\equiv 8 \equiv 1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod7$

$\color{green}{6}+\color{teal}{1}+2 \equiv 9 \equiv 2 \not\equiv 0\pmod7 $

$\color{purple}{2}+\color{lime}{4}+2\equiv 8 \equiv 1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod 7$

$\color{orange}{3}+\color{fuchsia}{2}+2\equiv 7 \equiv 0 \pmod 7 \checkmark$

$\color{aqua}{1}+\color{teal}{1}+2\equiv 4 \not\equiv 0 \pmod 7$

---

Note that $(5,7)=1$ and $(4,7)=1$ thus $4,5$ have inverses modulo $7$.

$\mathbf3\cdot 5\equiv 1\pmod 7, \: 5^{-1}\equiv 3 \pmod7$

$\mathbf2\cdot 4 \equiv 1 \pmod 7, \: 4^{-1}\equiv 2 \pmod7$

---

We could extend $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ because by Fermat’s Little Theorem

$a^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ where $(a,7)=1$

even if $m<0$ we could take the positive remainder modulo $6$, $a^z\equiv a^{z\pmod6}\pmod7$ because there exist inverses for $4,5$ modulo $7$, because in particular, $7$ is prime.

$5^{6m+5}+4^{6m+5}+2\equiv (5^{6})^m\cdot 5^5+ (4^6)^m\cdot 4^5+2\equiv 1^m\cdot5^5 + 1^m\cdot 4^5 +2\equiv 3+2+2\equiv 0\pmod7$

for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $n=6m+5\equiv 5 \pmod 6$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The possibilities are not so many: you have to find $n$ such that $5^n+4^n\equiv -2\equiv 5\mod 7$, and you can use thay, since $5$ has order $6$ and $4$ has order $3\bmod 7$,
$$5^n+4^n\equiv 5^{n\bmod 6}+4^{n\bmod 3}\mod 7.$$